# Add the new mobs to mcpi

Tags: python, minecraft, bukkit

Is there a way to add the newer mobs to the mcpi entities file I would like to add the glow squid entity I'm using Minecraft 1.19.4 and craft bukkit 1.19.4 and I'm using martin o' Hanlon's mcpi python module.

but when I run the program it displays:

```
raise RequestError("%s failed"%self.lastSent.strip())
```

mcpi.connection.RequestError: b'world.spawnEntity(-7.896357636911148,-2.0,263.23120782896757,201)' failed

i tried adding the mob to the entity file but it showed the error message